# Why does the lack of !empty($_GET) generate an error?

Tags: php

My PHP Code is :

```
<?php

    if ((!empty($_POST)) && ($_POST['action'] == 'addRunner'))
    {
        $fname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtFirstName']);
        $lname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtLastName']);
        $gender = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ddlGender']);
        $minutes = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtMinutes']);
        $seconds = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtSeconds']);

        if(preg_match('/[^\w\s]/i', $fname) || preg_match('/[^\w\s]/i', $lname)) 
        {
            fail('Invalid name provided.');
        }
        if( empty($fname) || empty($lname) ) 
        {
            fail('Please enter a first and last name.');
        }
        if( empty($gender) ) 
        {
            fail('Please select a gender.');
        }

        $time = $minutes.":".$seconds;
        $query = "INSERT INTO runners SET first_name='$fname', last_name='$lname',
        gender='$gender', finish_time='$time'";
        $result = db_connection($query);
        if ($result) 
        {
            $msg = "Runner: ".$fname." ".$lname." added successfully" ;
            success($msg);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            fail('Insert failed.');
        } 
        exit;
    }
    elseif($_GET['action'] == 'getRunners')
    {

        $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, gender, finish_time FROM runners ORDER BY finish_time ASC";
        $result = db_connection($query);

        $runners = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            array_push($runners, array('fname' => $row['first_name'], 'lname' => $row['last_name'], 'gender' => $row['gender'], 'time' => $row['finish_time']));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("runners" => $runners));
        exit;
    }

    function db_connection($query)
    {
        $dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','runner_db_user','runner_db_password','race_info')
            or die('Error connecting to Database');

        return mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    }

    function fail($message) 
    {
        die(json_encode(array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => $message)));
    }
    function success($message) 
    {
        die(json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $message)));
    }

?>
```

NOTE that the original code provided in the book read

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'addRunner')
```

instead of

```
if ((!empty($_POST)) && ($_POST['action'] == 'addRunner'))
```

However, the original code generates an error saying

> Notice: Undefined index: action in E:\wamp\www\Z_jquery\ch9\service.php on line 3

**I'm guessing this is because unless a POST request is generated, the value of $_POST['action'] isn't assigned a value. Is that correct?**

But, even though the code doesn't contain a step to check if `$_GET['action']` is empty or not, the code still runs perfectly, even if a POST Request occurs (and presumably `$_GET['action']` is NULL). Why does this happen?

Why does the following work:

```
elseif($_GET['action'] == 'getRunners')
```

and, why don't I have to write:

```
elseif((!empty($_GET)) && ($_GET['action'] == 'getRunners'))
```

> Note that http://localhost/z_jquery/ch9/service.php?action=addRunners generates an empty page, as expected, and no warnings or errors.

Comment: *..I'm guessing this is because unless a POST request is generated, the value of $_POST['action'] isn't assigned a value. Is that correct?* Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm guessing this is because unless a POST request is generated, the value of $_POST['action'] isn't assigned a value. Is that correct?*

Yes this is correct. Unless the request is a POST request, the `$_POST` array is  null.

---

*even if a POST Request occurs (and presumably $_GET['action'] is NULL). Why does this happen? Why does the following work: `elseif($_GET['action'] == 'getRunners')`*

This works because if the the request is a POST request it will enter the first `if` block and not actually run the `else if` or even attempt to be evaluated by the `else if` condition as it entered the first `if` block.

---

*Note that http://localhost/z_jquery/ch9/service.php?action=addRunners generates an empty page, as expected, and no warnings or errors.*

That would not generate any warning as your `else if` is looking for a GET parameter called `action`. If you ran this, `http://localhost/z_jquery/ch9/service.php?mytest=addRunners` you will get an undefined index warning as the parameter `action` doesn't exist in the GET array

Answer (score 1):

The empty test checks that $_POST EXISTS ( i.e. a form has posted data to this code rather than you just entering its URL in browser, which would not cause it to contain a payload of data) and because you are using an `&&` if $_POST does not exists it wont bother doing the second test, which would generate the error if `$_POST` did not exist.